# How to delete all objects from my R environment except two that have different names

Tags: r, regex

Sometimes I have in my R environment tens of objects and I want to keep only one, two, or three of them. As an example:

```
df1   df8    dataframeX
df2   df9    ObjectY
df3   df10   df15
df4   df11   df16
df5   df12   dataframeZ
df6   df13
df7   df14
```

I found this useful script to retain one or several objects that follow the same name pattern:

```
rm(list = grep("^dataframe", ls(), value = TRUE, invert = TRUE))

dataframeX
dataframeZ
```

However, I don't know how to modify it to keep in my R environment objects which follow different name's patterns. For example, how could I keep the objects `dataframeX`, `dataframeZ` and `ObjectY?.

Does anyone know how to create a script that allows me to do that easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
rm(list = grep("^(?:dataframe|Object)", ls(), value = TRUE, invert = TRUE))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zM5Vbu/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `dataframe` - a `dataframe` string
  - `|` - or
  - `Object` - an `Object` string
- `)` - end of grouping.

The group is used to make sure the `^` is applied to both the alternatives, so that they were searched for at the start of a string only.

Comment: That's perfect!!!. I had tried `rm(list = grep("^dataframe" | "^Object", ls(), value = TRUE, invert = TRUE))`. But as you explained, this wasn't the proper language. Thank you very much for the explanation.